# specifying Css Class in Html.ValueFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display the `name` attribute of my model with a CSS class when calling `Html.ValueFor(x => x.Name)`.

How can this be done using `@Class` or other?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="YOUR CLASS NAME">
if(Model!=null){
@Model.Name
}
</span>
```

Comment: Span is not working in the following line. Html.RowInput(Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, "Name:",new {@class = "css-label"}), Html.ValueFor(x => x.Name), false, "frm-name"))

Comment: May be you should use another helper, e.g. DisplayFor(x => x.Name, "CustomStyleTemplateView") in such case?